# How To Update a Table with several changes in values with a LOAD csv file?

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-workbench

I have an existing Stores_Master table, with existing columns and values like, Storenumber (Primary Key), Store_Name, Location, inactive_flag, and Region_Number. Over time this table has developed various little inconsistencies, like the Location values, some values say "NY" for the state instead of "New York". So I exported the whole table in a csv file and went through and made a bunch of little typo corrections in different columns. I can't figure out how to update the table, using the Storenumber as the column to map with, to update this table. Here is the closest I've gotten:

USE My_Database;

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Users/LK/Desktop/Stores_Reno_Update_12.28.23.csv'
INTO TABLE Stores_Master
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS

(
Storenumber,
Store_Name,
Location,
region_num,
inactive_flag)

ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Storenumber = new.Storenumber;

The error message I am getting is that the "ON" part of "ON DUPLICATE KEY" is not valid at that position. Any help?

Comment: If the changes in the csv file are not cumulative then what?

Answer (score 0):

The [load](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html) command doesn't seem to have a `on duplicate` clause.

Why not load your CSV into a new table?  You can then overwrite the old table like:

```
UPDATE  Stores_Master ot
JOIN    CsvImportTable nt
ON      ot.Storenumber = nt.Storenumber
SET     ot.Store_Name = nt.Store_Name
,       ot.Location = nt.Location
```

You can delete the new table afterwards.